# Problem with roscore

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I have problem with *roscore*. When I try to run *roscore* I give this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/**init**.py", line 230, in main
write_pid_file(options.pid_fn, options.core, options.port)
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/**init**.py", line 106, in write_pid_file
with open(pid_fn, "w") as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.ros/roscore-11311.pid'

Does someone know how I can fix it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60366/problem-with-roscore/) by [Roboticus](https://answers.ros.org/users/4649/roboticus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-04-09**:
If you have *source /root/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash* in your .bashrc remove it, create the catkin workspace again and check.

**Comment by [Roboticus](https://answers.ros.org/users/4649/roboticus/) on 2013-04-09**:
It still doesn't work. I deleted my existing workspace, source from .bashrc and create new ones still appears this error. Maybe someone else know how fix this problem. I reinstall whole ROS and still nothing. I'm begginer in ROS.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-10**:
Something is setup wrong. You can't write to the .ros directory or that specific file. What do you get for `id -a`, `ls -la .ros`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,
the problem could be that you ran rosdep update with sudo rights. That leads to permission errors later on.

NOTE : Run rosdep update NOT with sudo.

SOLUTION to fix this run sudo rosdep fix-permissions

and after that rosdep update.

Worked for me.

cheers

Timo

---

Originally posted by [Timo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21625/timo/) with karma: 86 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [imAsim](https://answers.ros.org/users/21893/imasim/) on 2015-03-17**:
Perfect it does the trick for me. I was running programs from 'ROS by Example for Hydro - Volume 1'. I was not able to execute
$ roslaunch rbx1_bringup fake_turtlebot.launch
or
$ roslaunch rbx1_bringup fake_pi_robot.launch

I would get 'IOERROR [Error13] ...'. Anyhow it is fixed now. Thanks!

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2015-09-08**:
the rosdep fix-permissions command worked for me!

**Comment by [kjerath](https://answers.ros.org/users/25060/kjerath/) on 2015-11-10**:
Worked like a charm...

**Comment by [Vijay](https://answers.ros.org/users/25970/vijay/) on 2016-02-16**:
Awesome ,it worked.. than q @imAsim

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem running roscore. The problem was that the hidden folder " ~/.ros" required root rights.

To solve it, I deleted the folder with:

> sudo su
> rm -R ~/.ros/

After that, roscore worked well and a new .ros folder was created automatically.

---

Originally posted by [MachR](https://answers.ros.org/users/4501/machr/) with karma: 1 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-10**:
If .ros required root rights, something was wrong before. Maybe some sudo call. ROS doesn't set the up as root.

**Comment by [MachR](https://answers.ros.org/users/4501/machr/) on 2013-04-10**:
Yes, there was a mistake in the groovy installation documentation, saying to run the command  with sudo. This leads to the error. The documentation is corrected now.

**Comment by [zurish](https://answers.ros.org/users/20878/zurish/) on 2015-02-11**:
It doesn't work. When I entered the two command lines "rm: cannot remove ‘/root/.ros/’: No such file or directory" showed up. What is the problem?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-12**:
You are in the home of the root user, not in the home of the user, where you want to remove the .ros directory.

**Comment by [zurish](https://answers.ros.org/users/20878/zurish/) on 2015-02-12**:
@dornhege Thanks it's working now.

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2017-04-10**:
Worked like charm. But could you please explain what .ros contains? I thought it only stored the logs.